# Orientation delegate method is not getting called while rotating the tabs under more section

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, orientation

In my project the tabs which are not under more section are properly responding to orientation but the tabs present under the more section are not responding.
For example if I am having two tabs names tab1 and tab2 under more section and if I am putting break point at the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method of each tab.After that when if I am selecting tab1 from more section and tries to rotate it but the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" of the tab2 gets called.The delagate method of the tab which I am selecting is not getting called.I am working on XCode Ver 4.3.2.
Can someone please help me in solving this problem..

Thanks in advance,
Prajnaranjan Das

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write followings code of all the root view controller of tab bar controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

 return yes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks IOSCODER but I have done this in all the root view controllers.only the tabs which are present outside of the more tab are working properly but the tabs under more section is not working

Comment: i have the same problem please let me know if you have solution.

Answer (score 1):

i face the same prblm as you facing now...

i was Return YES (shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Function) to all the view Controller classes inside tababarcontroller and my problem solved..

try to do this...might be you also get success

Comment: Thanks for your reply but had also tried this way which you are telling me but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method for orientation. Its working properly.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
}
```

There are several other methods which may help you in orientation such as:

• willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

• didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

• willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation

• willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation